# .find() and .closest() not getting my elements

Tags: jquery

I want to fill a `div` dynamically suing jQuery. Now the problem is the following:

Using `.closest()` does not fill my `div#articleDetail` with `divs` of classes
`.date`, `.views` and `.count`. Since I believe `.closest()` climbs **up** the DOM and not **down**.

Only the name in the `h4` tags gets filled into the bottom `div` (`#articledetail`)

HTML:

```
<div id="make" class="span12">
    <article class="make"> <a href=""><img src="../img/175x175.jpg" alt="" /></a>

        <div class="content">
             <h4><a class="merc" href="#latestClick">Mercedes-Benz</a></h4>

            <div class="date">12 March 2013</div>
            <div class="count"><span></span> photos</div>
            <div class="views">Views: <span>32</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </article>
    <article class="make latest"> <a href=""><img src="../img/175x175.jpg" alt="" /></a>

        <div class="content">
             <h4><a class="bmw" href="#latestClick">BMW</a></h4>

            <div class="date">12 March 2013</div>
            <div class="count"><span></span> photos</div>
            <div class="views">Views: <span>89</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </article>
</div>
<div id="articleDetail"></div>
```

JS:

```
$('#make article h4 a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#latestInner, #make, #models').hide(200);
    $('#article').show(500);
    //fill articleDetail (name, date, views, count)
    $('#articleDetail').empty();
    $(this).closest('.date').clone().appendTo('#articleDetail'); //date
    $(this).closest('.count').clone().appendTo('#articleDetail'); //count
    $(this).closest('.views').clone().appendTo('#articleDetail'); //views
    $(this).parent().clone().appendTo('#articleDetail'); //name
.....
```

Any suggestions how I can achieve this?

**NOTE:** I do **NOT** want to add ID's and I do not want to change the structure of my HTML. There has to be a way to call and append the appropriate classes to `#articledetail`.

```
.views .count and .date
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`closest` finds the closest ascendant that matches the given selector. However in your markup `<div class="date">` is not an ancestor of `a` element, and therefore nothing is found. What should work though is something like:

```
$(this).closest('.content').find('.date')
```

Comment: thank you man, appreciate. You were first so I will give you the points

Answer (score 2):

You are right `.closest` goes up the tree, not down. The elements you want to find are all children of the link's grandparent. So what do you do? You find the grandparent first and then search its children:

```
var $content = $(this).closest('.content');
$content.find('.date').clone().appendTo('#articleDetail');
// ...
```

Comment: appreciate your answer, thank you. Unfortunately Andrei was first

Answer (score 1):

Just climb up to the wrapper, and find stuff inside it:

```
$(this).closest('.content').find('.date.')
```